# I'm trying to dispose of an object when the system is low on memory - is there a better way than this?

Tags: asp.net, caching

What I am doing currently is adding an item to the Cache and disposing of my object when that object is removed from the Cache. The logic being that it gets removed when memory consumption gets too high. I'm open to outher suggestions but I would like to avoid creating a thread than continually measures memory statistics if possible. Here is my code:

```
public class WebServiceCache : ConcurrentDictionary<string, WebServiceCacheObject>, IDisposable
{
    private WebServiceCache()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Cache != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add("CacheTest", true, null, DateTime.Now.AddYears(1), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, 
                System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Low, 
                (key, obj, reason) => {
                    if (reason != System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason.Removed)
                    {
                        WebServiceCache.Current.ClearCache(50);
                    }
                });
        }
    }

    private static WebServiceCache _current;
    public static WebServiceCache Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (_current != null && _current.IsDisposed)
            {
                // Might as well clear it fully
                _current = null;
            }
            if (_current == null)
            {
                _current = new WebServiceCache();
            }
            return _current;
        }
    }


    public void ClearCache(short percentage)
    {
        try
        {
            if (percentage == 100)
            {
                this.Dispose();
                return;
            }
            var oldest = _current.Min(c => c.Value.LastAccessed);
            var newest = _current.Max(c => c.Value.LastAccessed);
            var difference = (newest - oldest).TotalSeconds;
            var deleteBefore = oldest.AddSeconds((difference / 100) * percentage);
            // LINQ doesn't seem to work very well on concurrent dictionaries
            //var toDelete = _current.Where(c => DateTime.Compare(c.Value.LastAccessed,deleteBefore) < 0);
            var keys = _current.Keys.ToArray();
            foreach (var key in keys)
            {
                if (DateTime.Compare(_current[key].LastAccessed, deleteBefore) < 0)
                {
                    WebServiceCacheObject tmp;
                    _current.TryRemove(key, out tmp);
                    tmp = null;
                }
            }
            keys = null;
        }
        catch
        {
            // If we throw an exception here then we are probably really low on memory
            _current = null;
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }

    public bool IsDisposed { get; set; }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove("CacheTest");
        this.IsDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

In Global.asax

```
    void context_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = _context.Server.GetLastError();
        if (ex.InnerException is OutOfMemoryException)
        {
            if (_NgageWebControls.classes.Caching.WebServiceCache.Current != null)
            {
                _NgageWebControls.classes.Caching.WebServiceCache.Current.ClearCache(100);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Why are you doing this?  Just use the ASP.NET Cache and don't try to roll your own.  BTW you can reference the ASP.NET Cache as `HttpRuntime.Cache` - you don't need an `HttpContext` to use it.

Comment: Will HttpRuntime.Cache always be available no matter what stage of the page request lifecycle I am in? Or if I was to access it from a different thread or somehing? If so then great I'll just use that instead.

Comment: The cache will remove objects and make them available for disposal by itself if there is memory pressure. The Garbage Collector will collect objects by itself it there is memory pressure. Fix your memory leaks instead of trying to second-guess the system, eg. by setting an expiration of MINUTES instead of a YEAR, or by specifying a sliding expiration of minutes to ensure only useful objects remain in the cache

Comment: @Panagiotis: That object is meant to never exire, herce the AddYear(). I'm not doing this because I have memory leaks - I'm doing this because I want to cache lots and lots of data, potentially more data than will fit in memory.

Comment: So you want to cache in memory more data than will fit in memory? I believe you misunderstand what the Cache is and does. Perhaps you should be looking for a solution like memcached or AppFabric Cache, not the ASP.NET Cache

Comment: I want to cache as much as possible in memory and then selectively remove objects when memory consumption becomes an issue, read the ClearCache method above. I was thinking of using AppFabric cache.

Comment: @JoeNFU - Yes, the Cache is available from any thread, at any stage of the page lifecycle, or even when you're not in the context of an HTTP Request (e.g. a background thread).

Comment: Great, I'll use that then - if you want to post that I shouldn't need to do this as an aswer then I'll mark it best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the ASP.NET Cache from anywhere in your application as the static property:

```
HttpRuntime.Cache
```

You don't need to be in the context of a Request (i.e. don't need `HttpContext.Current`) to do this.

So you should be using it instead of rolling your own caching solution.